# Как получить id канала и отправить туда сообщение

Tags: python, discord.py

у меня есть команда `\createC` - она создаёт 5 каналов, но как получить id этих каналов и отправить туда сообщение после создания

```
@botm.command()
async def createC(ctx):
    guild = ctx.message.guild
    n=0
    while(n<=int(botsettings["CreateChannels"])):
        await guild.create_text_channel(f'channel n {n}') 
        #как в этот канал, который только что создался отправить сообщение?
        n = n+1
```

Comment: попробуйте записывать объект канал в переменную: `channel = await guild.create_text_channel(f'channel n {n}') `

Comment: а как туда отправить сообщение? @denisnumb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция `await guild.create_text_channel(f'channel n {n}')`  возращает созданный канал, так что канал можно получить, поместив функцию в переменную. Код будет выглядеть так:

```
@botm.command()
async def createC(ctx):
    guild = ctx.guild
    n = 0
    while (n <= int(botsettings["CreateChannels"])):
        channel = await guild.create_text_channel(f'channel n {n}') 
        await channel.send("сообщение")
        n += 1
```

И ещё, на будущее) От `ctx` можно напрямую получить и гильдию, и канал и всё что хочешь, через сообщение это делать не надо. Вместо `guild = ctx.message.guild` используй `guild = ctx.guild`. И вместо `n = n + 1`, можно использовать `n += 1`, это работает и с другими действиями. Например:
`n *= 2`, `n /= 3` и тд.

Comment: сейчас проверю, заранее спасибо!

Comment: не работает, ошибка

Comment: в какой строке?

Comment: а, теперь работает, просто я в переменной guild = ctx.message.guild забыл message убрать